# Open Kivy Settings inside Screen from NavigationDrawer

Tags: python, kivy

I want to open the kivy settings inside a screen from the kivymd navigationdrawer. The default settings only open in a new window that completely ignore the color theme of the app. Any suggestion on how to make the settings a child of the screen manager?

Here is the guiApp.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
import kivymd
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.uix.settings import Settings, SettingsWithSidebar

class guiApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'BlueGray'
    theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'

    def build(self):
        self.settings_cls = SettingsWithSidebar

guiApp().run()
```

and the gui.kv:

```
NavigationLayout:
     MDNavigationDrawer:
          NavigationDrawerSubheader:
               text: 'Operation Menu'

          NavigationDrawerIconButton:
               icon: 'information-outline'
               text: 'Introduction'
               on_release: screen_manager.current = 'screen_info'

          NavigationDrawerIconButton:
               icon: 'settings'
               text: 'Settings'
               on_release: screen_manager.current = 'screen_settings'
               on_release: app.open_settings()

BoxLayout:
          orientation: 'vertical'
          MDToolbar:
               title: 'My GUI'
               md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
               left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

          ScreenManager:
               id: screen_manager

               Screen:
                    name: 'screen_info'

                    MDLabel:
                         text: 'This page will be used for information on how to use the App '
                         theme_text_color : 'Hint'
                         valign: 'middle'
                         halign: 'center'
               Screen:
                    name: 'screen_settings'
                    BoxLayout:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using app.open_settings(), you can use app.create_settings(), to get the setting widget, that you can directly attach to a **Screen**.

Add the **on_start** method to **guiApp** class

```
[...]
class guiApp(App):
    [...]

    def on_start(self):
        s = self.create_settings()
        self.root.ids.settings_content.add_widget(s)
```

And give an id to the BoxLayout of your **screen_settings**

```
[...]
Screen:
    name: 'screen_settings'
    BoxLayout:
        id: settings_content
```

Comment: It works great. I only have to match the color of the setting page to the 'theme' of my app. Thanks.